# to create our own custom exception, throw or throws or try & catch?

Tags: java, try-catch, throw, throws

in Java If we want to create our own custom exception, which keyword should we use?

throw or throws or try & catch?

Comment: What have you tried already? What documentation have you read on the topic?

Comment: `class Something extends Exception { }`

Comment: First acquire a thorough understanding of the exceptions concept (which you apparently don't have right now), before you invent your own custom exceptions. Otherwise your code will become a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new class that extends the class Exception. Throws keyword is used to indicate that the current class propagate exceptions, throw keyword is used to launch the propagation and try catch determined a block where the exception is captured.

```
 public class MyClass extend Exception {
         public MyClass(String msg)
             super(msg);
}
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. it was really helpful